# special character that comes last in alphabetical order sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I need to put a record at last of the result set ordered by a column field in ascending order.

LIKE:

```
SELECT "#TOTAL"...
```

Which is a user-defined column value.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
        SELECT cnt.name as Client, NULL, NULL, NULL, ', @COL_SUM, '
        FROM
        task as tsk

        LEFT JOIN client cnt
            ON tsk.client_id = cnt.id            
        GROUP BY tsk.client_id 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT "#TOTAL#",NULL,NULL,NULL, ', @COL_SUM, '
        FROM task as tsk

        ORDER BY Client ASC
```

This returns result set as:

```
Client  | ... | Admin  |  Intern | ..
---------------------------------------
#TOTAL# | ... | 4      |  2      | .. <-- this row here is grand total
A       | ... | 1      |         | ..
B       | ... | 1      |  1      | ..
C       | ... | 2      |  1      | ..
```

I want the `#TOTAL#` row to be at last.

What character, except `z`, comes at last in alphabetical order?

Comment: This is still too vague and ambiguous.  What does your data look like and what do you want your results to look like? Give specific examples - there are almost certainly better ways to achieve this than fudging characters based on sort order.

Comment: If you're wondering about which characters you can add to something for it to be sorted last, this [ascii table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) should be able to help.


EDIT: Looking up any ASCII table should do the trick if that link stops working.


Writing `|TOTAL|`, `{TOTAL}`, or `~TOTAL~` should do the trick.

Comment: @AleksG I have updated my post.. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: @LiHRaM But do be mindful of non-latin characters

Comment: Where is this data to be used?  If you plan to output it somewhere in the code, it might be better to _not_ include the total into your sql.  Instead, as you output line data, add the values on the fly - then output the totals.  This way it'll always be last.

Comment: basically you want to add total at the last of your query result.

Comment: @DarkRob yes that is it.

Comment: @Azima Did the answers help or do you need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your condition to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
order by Client = '#TOTAL#', Client
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this variant of code.

For `mysql`:

```
    SELECT 0 as [OrderBy], cnt.name as Client, NULL, NULL, NULL, ', @COL_SUM, '
    FROM
    task as tsk 
    LEFT JOIN client cnt
        ON tsk.client_id = cnt.id            
    GROUP BY tsk.client_id      
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 , "#TOTAL#",NULL,NULL,NULL, ', @COL_SUM, '
    FROM task as tsk
    ORDER BY [ORDERBY], cLIENT_ID
```

For `sql server`

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT cnt.name as Client, NULL, NULL, NULL, ', @COL_SUM, '
    FROM
    task as tsk 
    LEFT JOIN client cnt
        ON tsk.client_id = cnt.id            
    GROUP BY tsk.client_id 
    ORDER BY TSK.CLIENT_ID) AS DATA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "#TOTAL#",NULL,NULL,NULL, ', @COL_SUM, '
    FROM task as tsk
```

Since you are not able to apply order by in the first part of your query, so there is a method to do so, `top 100 percent`, and you can apply `order by` clause in your inner query or sub query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another constant column to the individual queries that indicate if it's a total or a regular row and order by that first.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT 0 first_order,
                    cnt.name client,
                    ...
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 first_order,
                    '#TOTAL#' client,
                    ...) x
       ORDER BY first_order,
                client;
```